# Keplerian telescope with parabolic mirrors

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics, telescopes

Is it possible to arrange two off axis parabolic mirrors (OPAs) to transform the emitted rays of a point source into a collimated beam, as in the figure below?

[image]

That is, similar to a Keplerian telescope, but achieved with mirrors and not lenses.

**EDIT:** I want to desing an optical system that takes a point souce and collimates it to a beam of specific width, given that optics manufacturers (ThorLabs, Edmund, Newport) have OPA mirrors with foci at only discrete, large steps. Of course, lenses can do that as well but I want to avoid chromatic abberations, therefore the use of mirrors.

As is well known, a parabolic mirror can focus a collimated beam to a point at the parabola's focus. I came up with the following two configurations, which are somewhat similar, but not identical to the one I mentioned above:

[image]

<sub>Figures created with the help of [ricktu288's simulator](https://ricktu288.github.io/ray-optics/simulator/).</sub>

It seems to me that to achieve the "Keplerian telescope", I need to position the point source not at the focus of the parabolic mirror. But I would like to ask for help with finding this point.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The name is Kepler.

Comment: 2 parabolic mirrors are not a great choice for that configuration. A spherical mirror followed by a parabolic mirror would do better, but then a 45° angle is not a great choice on a spherical mirror, as you would need to adjust the angle of the parabolic mirror to compensate the astigmatism. But even better than that, simply a flat mirror followed by the parabolic mirror, with no intermediate image of the point source. This way you just need to adjust the parabolic mirror to the same focal distance.

Comment: This is an off-axis Gregorian telescope.

Comment: @JoséAndrade Quote "simply a flat mirror followed by the parabolic mirror, ... adjust the parabolic mirror to the same focal distance". I don't see how an off axis parabolic mirror and a flat mirror would do that. Can you draw a schematic?

Comment: Are you OK with using a hyperbolic mirror along with a parabolic mirror, instead of two parabolic mirrors?  You have one focus of the hyperbolic mirror co-located with the focus of the parabolic mirror, and put your point source at the second focus of the hyperbolic mirror.

Comment: @BaddDadd I am ok with that. But please, can you draw a schematic?

Comment: @JohnDoty Correct, the idea is the same as a telescope — transform a collimated beam into a point source, except that I want to bend the light. A Gregorian, Newtonian, or Cassegrain telescope keeps the light on the same axis and I want the light to make a bend.

Comment: See, for example https://www.researchgate.net/figure/SOLAR-C-A-The-off-axis-Gregorian-system-with-a-045-m-diameter-primary-mirror-The_fig3_234155151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I meant in the comment, sorry for poor drawing skills:

[image]